# Remote file extension validation in ASP.NET MVC3 with C#?

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application that uploads a file from the users' hard drive and manipulates it. One requirement is that the file extension should be .xls(or xlsx).

I would like to **validate the file name** but I would like to know what is the best option in terms of **reusability** and **performance** (and of course best coding practices).

I have the following **Index** view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <br />
        <p><input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="23"/></p><br />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>        
    }
```

Called by the controller action method **Index**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("Index");
}
```

And the user response is handled by the **Index** action method (**HttpPost**):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    FileServices lfileServices = new FileServices();
    var lfilePath = lfileServices.UploadFile(file, "~/App_Data/uploads");
    //Manipulation;
}
```

Now I can use the `Path.GetExtension(filename)` in the FileServices to get the extension and then perform the check but it will be performed just after the upload completes.

I would like to do it once the user attempts to upload the file. The only thing that came up to my mind is create a Model(or better a **ViewModel**) and use the **remote validation** from **DataAnnotations**.

I saw a demonstration from Scott Hanselman live but it seemed like he was not really confortable with that because the application was compiling but was not performing the check.

Has anybody a good approach in order to perform such kind of **remote validation** or any other solution (jQuery for instance)?

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this using javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var selectedFile = $('#file').val();
        var matches = selectedFile.match(/\.(xlsx?)$/i);
        if (matches == null) {
            alert('please select an Excel file');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Of course this doesn't in any case free you from the obligation of performing the same check on the server because if the client has no javascript enabled that will be the only way. And even this wouldn't be 100% reliable as there is nothing preventing users from renaming any garbage file to `.xls` and upload it. Heuristics could be used on the server to try to *guess* the actual file type by looking at some known byte sequences.

---

UPDATE:

Example with remote AJAX validation (due to demand in the comments, I don't recommend it though). You could use the excellent [jquery.validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) which by the way comes bundled with ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="23" data-remote-val-url="@Url.Action("CheckExtension")"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            file: {
                remote: $('#file').data('remote-val-url')
            }
        },
        messages: {
            file: {
                remote: 'Please select an Excel file'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

and on the server:

```
public ActionResult CheckExtension(string file)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file ?? string.Empty);
    var validExtensions = new[] { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
    var isValid = validExtensions.Contains(extension, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    return Json(isValid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: thanks for your answer. What do you think about calling an action method instead of performing the checks in the jQuery?

Comment: @Francesco, I don't see the need. If all that this action will do is to verify the extension this could be done on the client. Why wasting bandwidth?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: for instance if you generalize the case and you want to reuse the functionality in other applications with different filetypes.

Comment: @Francesco, a [custom jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) seems like a good way to reuse functionality between different applications.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: what about the case when the filetypes suitable for the application are stored in a database?

Comment: @Francesco, a jquery plugin can take options. All that would be necessary is to couple it with some server side script that will allow to retrieve the extensions from the database and pass them to the view as view model so that the plugin could be configured.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: so getting back to my initial remark, can you implement the server-side script as a JSonResult method where you pass through the jQuery plugin the extension of the uploaded file?

Comment: @Francesco, of course you can, it's just a matter of sending an AJAX request, but as I said it would be a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: thanks! Sorry if I asked too many questions, even if the jQuery script was working, but I do not like to use Stackoverflow to ask and then copy-paste. I ask questions mainly to learn and everytime you teach me a lot of cool stuff

Comment: @Francesco, you shouldn't feel sorry for asking questions and wanting to learn. At the contrary. That's exactly the purpose of StackOverflow.